# Moles without Pex?

Tags: mocking, pex-and-moles, moles

Can Moles be used without having to use Pex?

Also, Does anyone know when MS Moles will have a Release candidate? I am hesitant of using it in the Production system without knowing which direction it will head.

Comment: Why would you use Moles in a production environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can Moles be used without having to use Pex?

Yes. They are freely available on Visual Studio Gallery.

Answer (score 1):

While they might be packaged together, Moles is a completely separate product from PEX and can be used independently.

As for using it on production, if you're only using it in your unit testing projects then you should not have to install Moles on your production environment as it will only be used in testing.